# how to find and remove duplicates documents from mongodb collection using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

how to find and remove duplicates documents from mongodb using python.
We have total 7 documents/records out of 2 documents/records are duplicate. so need to find those duplicate document/records and delete from same collection. In the documents we will have 100 attributes so we can not find documents based on few attributes. We need exact duplicate document/records

**MongoDB collection**

```
[
    { 'name': 'Amy', 'address': 'Apple st 652', 'age': 34 },
    { 'name': 'Hannah', 'address': 'Mountain 21', 'age': 34 },
    { 'name': 'Hannah', 'address': 'Mountain 21', 'age': 34 },
    { 'name': 'Amy', 'address': 'Apple st 652', 'age': 34 },
    { 'name': 'Richard', 'address': 'Sky st 331', 'age': 34 },
    { 'name': 'Chuck', 'address': 'Main Road 989', 'age': 34 },
    { 'name': 'Viola', 'address': 'Sideway 1633', 'age': 34 },
];
```

**Output Collection**

```
[
    { 'name': 'Amy', 'address': 'Apple st 652' },
    { 'name': 'Hannah', 'address': 'Mountain 21' },
    { 'name': 'Richard', 'address': 'Sky st 331' },
    { 'name': 'Chuck', 'address': 'Main Road 989' },
    { 'name': 'Viola', 'address': 'Sideway 1633' },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$$ROOT](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.ROOT) which represents the full document and group on that, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see we have to remove the `_id` field as it's unique and would ruin the approach, an additional point to consider is that this loads the entire collection into memory. If you machine can't handle it you have no other choice but to incorporate code and paginate over the collection.

Comment: Getting error: MongoServerError: Syntax error: $projection requires at least one output field.

Comment: Working fine in local but throwing error in QA env.

Comment: are you using MongoDB, or DocumentDB?

Comment: in local mongodb and in QA document db

Comment: it is give unique records only. it is not updating the collection

Comment: add an `$out` stage and it will overwrite the collection

Comment: Can we get duplicate records in mongodb shell instead of unique record

Answer (score 1):

```
db.dup_doc.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "name":"$name"
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$_id"
    }
  },
   { $out: 'dup_doc' }
])
```

Comment: This looks to be a thank you / confirmation of the accepted answer.